# apt: upgrade=safe removes eth0

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, ansible

I have a ansible playbook with following tasks

```
- name: Get aptitude for upgrade
  apt: pkg=aptitude state=present

- name: Update APT package cache
  apt: update_cache=yes cache_valid_time=3600
```

When I add

```
- name: Upgrade APT to the latest packages
  apt: upgrade=safe
```

the eth0 interface magically disappears.

**cat /etc/network/interfaces:**

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto etho0 
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

**ifconfig** before apt: upgrade=safe:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:9e:16:fd  
          inet addr:192.168.1.161  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::ba27:ebff:fe9e:16fd/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: 2002:5e4f:b23c:1234:ba27:ebff:fe9e:16fd/64 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:95254 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:30815 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:136917073 (136.9 MB)  TX bytes:2880058 (2.8 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:160 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:160 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:11840 (11.8 KB)  TX bytes:11840 (11.8 KB)
```

and after:

```
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:160 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:160 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:11840 (11.8 KB)  TX bytes:11840 (11.8 KB)
```

I am running a fresh Ubuntu server 16.04 LTS. Any ideas why eth0 disappears? Obiously apt: upgrade=safe is the issue but why?

**ifconfig -a** surprisingly gives a different output, however eth0 still missing:

[image]

Comment: Is your eth0 actually _gone_ or simply "not up" (ifconfig -a)?

Comment: @grawity I added the output of ifconfig -a

Answer (score 0):

After installing network-manager the problem disappeared

```
- name: Get network-manager
  apt: state=installed pkg=network-manager
```